# What does this SQL statement including 'WHERE (1) = [condition]' mean?

Tags: sql

I was reading up on some SQL concepts and came across this example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (1) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
    FROM Employee Emp2
    WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
)
```

What does this script do?

Lines that confuse me:
*1)* `WHERE (1)`
This means '`WHERE` the following query is `TRUE`', but why is this needed?

*2)* `WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary`
Returns rows whose salaries are higher than itself...?

Comment: The sub-query returns a count so the condition is only true if that count equals 1

Comment: tkim90, can you review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The script returns all employee rows where there is exactly one employee who earns more.

Answer (score 0):

I've attached my answers below to respond to your "confusing lines".

1) 'WHERE (1)'
This means 'WHERE the following query is TRUE', but why is this needed?

**[Answer]** This `WHERE` condition is met when your inner select statement returns 1, because it evaluates 1=1 which actually means `WHERE TRUE`.

2) 'WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary
Returns rows whose salaries are higher than itself...?

**[Answer]** This condition is a comparison made across the entire `Employee` table.

Consider a following example data of `Employee` table:

```
Salary
------
222.55
333.66
```

The first `SELECT` statement would fetch both of those rows and then the second query would fetch salaries that are higher than the current one being compared (for each). This means, that it has a value `333.66` inside `COUNT()` function and there is exactly one salary that is higher than `222.55`, since `333.66 is not higher than 333.66` - so this row gets discarded from result.